# Change CPIO format to newc without extraction

Tags: cpio, file-roller

I am trying to create modify an u-boot filesystem image. At first I tried to extract, modify and then pack it again, but that didn't work, because extracting and repacking seems to mess up the ownerships of the files. So I tried to modify it, without explicit extraction using file-roller. This should work, but sadly file-roller saves the file in the wrong format and doesn't let me change the format.

So is there a way to convert a .cpio to newc-format without extracting it?

Before I used the following commands to extract and pack:

```
cpio -idv --no-absolute-filenames < ../filesystem.cpio
find . -print | cpio -ov -H newc > ../output.cpio
```

Comment: if you extract the cpio as root you will preserve the ownerships.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! Do you want to put that into an answer so you can get the rep for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you extract the cpio as root you will preserve the ownerships.